# compare and contrast a 2p6 orbital to a 4s1 using quantum numbers to help

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Would you be able to help me understand how to compare and contrast a 2p6 orbital to a 4s1 using quantum numbers to help?

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to answer your question yourself. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you, and that the Q/A is beneficial for broad audience.   As "homework-like questions" are considered literal homeworks, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.  Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this. See [Homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448).  Otherwise, the question may get closed as "low effort homework-like question."

Answer (score 1):

$2\mathrm{p}^6$, $4\mathrm{p}^1$ are not orbitals.

It is a partial description of an atom electron configuration, saying there are 6 electrons in 3 orbitals $2\mathrm{p}$, respectively 1 electron in the orbital $4\mathrm{s}$.

$2$ in $2\mathrm{p}$ means the (main, energy ) quantum number $n=2$. $n$ can have values 1, 2, .....

$p$ in $2\mathrm{p}$ means the ( orbital, orbital angular momentum) quantum number $\ell=1$. $\ell$ can have values 0, 1, ...  , $n$ - 1.

The ( magnetic ) quantum number $m$ ( $-\ell \le m \le +\ell$ ) is for the axis projection of the vector of the electron orbital momentum ), determining e.g. there is

- 1 orbital $n\mathrm{s}$
- 3 orbitals $n\mathrm{p}$, called $\mathrm{p_x, p_y,p_z}$
- 5 orbitals $n\mathrm{d}$, called $\mathrm{d_{{xy}^2}, d_{{xz}^2}, d_{{yz}^2}, d_{x^2-y^2}, d_{z^2}}$
- 7 orbitals $n\mathrm{f}$, being seldom explicitly named.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital?wprov=sfla1).

---

In a hydrogen atom, or ions with just 1 electrons, orbitals with the same $n$ have the same energy(*).

In multielectron atoms, electrons in different orbitals have different interaction with other electrons and their energy differ. Their energy increases in order $\mathrm{s < p < d < f}$

Generally, but with multi exceptions, the energy ( and filling order) increases in this order:

1s 2s 2p 3s 3p 4s 3d 4p 5s 4d 5p 6s 4f 5d 6p 7s 5f 4d 7p

---

The naming has historical origin in spectroscopy. s as sharp, p as principal, d as diffuse, f as fundamental.

1. s means $\ell = 0$
2. p means $\ell = 1$
3. d means $\ell = 2$
4. f means $\ell = 3$

---

Orbitals have 3 meanings:

1. A wave function being  a particular solution of the Schroedinger wave equation, with integer constants $n, l, m$ called quantum numbers.
2. An electron quantum state with the particular $n, l, m$ values
3. A 3D shape, describing the probable electron occurence, with borders defined by occurence probability threshold, corresponding to 1 and 2.

---

(*) Relativistic corrections for Schroedinger  equation reveals and explain observations it is not fully true.